# How can i achieve a text-glow effect in ie(7+)?

Tags: jquery, html, glow, css

the question says it all xD

Using CSS, JQuery Or both how can i make text glow.

Is it possible?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "glow"

Comment: basically the exact same effect you would acheive with text-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #fff;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text glow is dead easy in CSS3, using `text-shadow`.

However, neither IE7 nor IE8 support this feature at all, and I don't know of any hacks that can make it work in these browsers. (other CSS3 features can be hacked into IE7/8, using tools like [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com), but not `text-shadow` as far as I know.

So unfortunately I think you're out of luck.

If you're okay with this solution not working in IE7 and IE8, then there's a reference on how to do it here: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/text-shadow (see the bottom section of the page for glowing effects)

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't. IE8 neither IE7 does use css3 so it isn't possible. maybe you can do it as an image

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible in ie 9 / css3 enabled browsers ... but in ie 7 and 8 I am afraid it not possible :/

Edit-

A friend suggested that maybe using the text-shadow css style could help you.

Comment: yh but its not compatible with any internet explorer.. Stupid ie not upholding standards..

Answer (score 0):

Css `text-shadow` can be faked by duplicating element with text, and positioning it relatively to original. There are numerous scripts to do this, one of them [here](http://labs.dragoninteractive.com/rainbows.php).
But the effort plus extra DOM manipultion in IE7 that is so slow by itself just isn't worth it imho.